# How to add timestamps in MongoDB when using MongoDB Adapter with next-auth

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next-auth

How to add timestamps in MongoDB when using MongoDB Adapter with next-auth?

This is my MongoDB adapter inside the NextAuthOptions:

```
//! To save the users who authenticates through Google or GitHub in the database.
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise, {
        databaseName: "Authentication",
        collections: {
            Accounts: "accounts",
            Users: "auths",
        }
    }),
```